# Dynamic Codable model, bind during runtime

Tags: json, swift, decoding

Codable struct created that decodes according to the response, some key on the response. But the api response send the key which decides the model to be used in parent json. How to access it inside: demo code below..

If the value is "First" then i want to use BodyResponse1, in all other cases use BodyResponse2

```
public protocol BodyResponse: Codable { }

struct BodyResponse1: BodyResponse {
    let title_1: String
    let description_1: String
}

struct BodyResponse2: BodyResponse {
    let title_2: String
    let description_2: String
}

struct BaseModel {
    let key: String
    let child_model: ChildModel?
}


struct ChildModel {
    let body: BodyResponse?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case body
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let value = "" // access the value for key in base model: how
        if value == "First" {
            body = try? BodyResponse1.init(from: container.superDecoder(forKey: .body))
        } else {
            body = try? BodyResponse2.init(from: container.superDecoder(forKey: .body))
        }
    }
}
```

Sample jsons:

```
{
  "key": "First",
    "child_model": {
      "body": {
        "title_1": "",
        "description_1": ""
      },
      "random_key": 12
    }
}

{
  "key": "Second",
    "child_model": {
      "body": {
        "title_2": "",
        "description_2": ""
      },
      "random_key": 12
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of all the keys that could be returned ? or it's dynamic also ?

Comment: keys inside body will have either body1 or body2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the keys in the `BaseModel`. Use `nestedContainer` to get the container for the child model.

```
struct BaseModel: Codable {
    let key: String
    let childModel: ChildModel?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key, childModel = "child_model"
    }
    
    enum ChildCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case body
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        key = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .key)
        let childContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ChildCodingKeys.self, forKey: .childModel)
        if key == "First" {
            childModel = ChildModel(body: try childContainer.decode(BodyResponse1.self, forKey: .body))
        } else if key == "Second" {
            childModel = ChildModel(body: try childContainer.decode(BodyResponse2.self, forKey: .body))
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .body, in: childContainer, debugDescription: "Unknown body response")
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(key, forKey: .key)
        var childContainer = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ChildCodingKeys.self, forKey: .childModel)
        if let response1 = childModel?.body as? BodyResponse1 {
            try childContainer.encode(response1, forKey: .body)
        } else if let response2 = childModel?.body as? BodyResponse2 {
            try childContainer.encode(response2, forKey: .body)
        } else {
            throw EncodingError.invalidValue(childModel?.body as Any, .init(codingPath: childContainer.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unknown body response type"))
        }
    }
}

// you might want to move "body" into BaseModel if ChildModel only has this one property.
struct ChildModel {
    let body: BodyResponse?
}
```

Comment: In addition you can also have `key`  as an enum type for better usage if you already know what keys to expect.

Comment: can we do similar way encoder also?